# JSON parsing in android app

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

The URL has the following view source.I need to parse and fetch the image path provided for "Folio".can anyone please guide how to get the array of the following paths.thanks in advance

```
     {"SEO":

  {"Marketing":["http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/Web.jpg","http://www.tts.com/imagepath/ranks.jpg"],
      "Folio":["http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_a_grade_motor_school.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_11.png",
                                   "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_abc_tarps.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_able_scale.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_accent_aluminum_windows.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_access_health.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_acmeda__zipscreen.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_11.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_aditya_birla_minerals.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_advanced_corporate_badges.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_aerotech_fans.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png",
                                              "http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.t.com.au_folio_portfolio_agriculture_victoria_services_.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png"]},

 "Services":{"Hosting":["http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/hostinga.jpg","http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/hostingb.jpg"],

  "Mobile Apps":["http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/mobileapp.jpg","http://www.tts.com/media/imagepath/mobilesite.jpg"]

}


}
```

The JSON parser class contains

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

The main activity contains

```
     public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static String url = "http://www.xyz.com/album_pro/array_to_encode";
    private static final String TAG_FOLIO = "SEO";
     JSONArray folio = null;
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
              StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


            try{

                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                Log.v("URL",json.toString());
            JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
            Log.v("seo",seo.toString());
            JSONArray folio = json.getJSONArray("Folio");

            for(int i=0;i< folio.length();i++)
            {
                Log.v("Test", "test");
            }


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
}
```

The error iam getting after runnning the app in logcat file is as follows

```
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230): org.json.JSONException: No value for Folio
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at com.example.testgallery.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:37)
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-04 15:36:50.458: W/System.err(23230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: the json you have provided is not valid.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 valid as in the format ??

Comment: Now It seems to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly create an ArrayList like...

```
ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Get Folio JSONArray from JSONObject Marketing like...

```
JSONArray folio = marketing.getJSONArray("Folio");
```

Now put all items from folio to urlList like...

```
for(int i=0;i<folio.length();i++){
  urlList.add(folio.getString(i));
}
```

Now you can use this urlList.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject seoObj = jObj.getJSONObject("SEO");
JSONArray folioArr = seoObj.getJSONArray("Folio");
ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < folioArr.length(); i++) {
image_urls.add(folioArr.getString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this JSON in a `String` variable called `stringSource`.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringSource);
JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
JSONArray folio = json.getJSONArray("Folio");
```

Then use `JSONArray.getString(int index)` to retrieve each URL from array.

Answer (score 0):

Convert  your Response to `String`

Then

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
//Since Folio is an array
JSONArray folio = json.getJSONArray("Folio");
//Get Individual Links
for(int i=0;i<folio.length();i++){
   //Fetch Your Code Here
   String image = folio.getString(i);

}
```

NB: I think you got an invalid JSON response . I checked your response [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Take this class

```
    public class GettingResponseFromUrl {

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static String GetDataFromServer(String url, String method) {
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        String Root_Response = null;
        try {
            HttpParams basicparams = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 120000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(basicparams,
                    timeoutConnection);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(basicparams);
            URI uri = new URI(url);
            HttpResponse res = null;
            if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
                res = client.execute(httpPost);
            } else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
                res = client.execute(httpGet);
            }
            InputStream data = res.getEntity().getContent();
            Root_Response = convertStreamToString(data);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Root_Response;
    }

}
```

//than call web service from below code

```
new GettingData().execute();

    private class GettingData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            private String response;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
try {
            Response = GettingResponseFromUrl
                    .GetDataFromServer(URL, "POST");
            Log.e("Response", Response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this tool which is freely available

[Android Class Creator tool](http://www.tejasj.com/rocking-json-parsing-tool-for-android/)

It's tutorial is with it. It's so easy to use.